# ChildFragmentManager + ViewPager + Animation = not good

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app build on many fagments and i change this fragments with horizontal slide animation. Some fragments contain ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. In process of restoring fragments from backstack i see black page of adapter.

[image: replacing from right to left]

[image: restoring from back stack]
Looks like childfragmentmanager in FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroed too soon. How to fix that?

Comment: Hello, how have you managed the slide animation inside the childFragmentManager? I want to do this also, using a vertical swiping

Answer (score 1):

It 's simple done with setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfFragment you want to retain).